# Xamarin.Android - how to implement callbacks used in universal image loader library

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, universal-image-loader

I am using Android-Universal-Image-Loader library to load images from urls asynchronously which works fine but i need some syntactical help understanding how the callbacks used in universalImageLoader for android in java would be implemented for xamarin.android in c#.

Here is the java code snippet which is used to load images in UniversalImageLoader with callbacks implemented .

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
@Override
public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
    ...
}
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    ... 
}
@Override
public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
    ...
}
}, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
    ...
}
});
```

}

How would i achieve this result in c# .

Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/LukeForder/Xamarin-Bindings-Android-Universal-Image-Loader ?
Usually callbacks are implemented as events in C#.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: yes those are the bindings that i am using , also here image loading listener is an interface type , i managed to get the call back in the methods i implemented for this interface in my class . But i don't know how to get the call backs inside this method definition itself ,which is happening here . i am limited by scope rules .

Answer (score 2):

figured out how to implement this in c# .

1. You need to implement the interface in your working class where you're making the method call . i.e provide method declarations for interface methods.

   ```
   public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap     loadedImage) {


   // here you will receive the callback

   }
   ```
2. initialize the interface 
   ImageLoadingListener interfaceName = new ClassName();
3. pass this interfaceName instance to display image method.
   eg. 
   `imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView, options, interfaceName);`
4. After that you will get the callbacks in the methods you implemented in your current class.